# Auth0 : How to call external API from Action?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

There is a need to call external API from "Action" during logging in.
At the moment, I have configured Auth0 portal using the following link:-
https://community.auth0.com/t/how-do-i-call-my-api-from-an-action/69041

I am running the api locally which is connected to Auth0.
From Actions, I am able to call the following from Action:-

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.status);
      console.log(response.statusText);
      console.log(response.headers);
      console.log(response.config);
    });
```

I have API which is running locally(locally) and I want to use that same API in Action (Web API is not exposed on internet yet) but its not working. I know this sounds bizzare calling locally running API in Action but I still would like to know, if there is way to call this api in Action.

Any input would be helpful.

FYI - I am able to generate a token.

best regards

Comment: You mean you want to call  "https://api.github.com/users/mapbox"  in locally ? The "https://api.github.com/users/mapbox" is protected by the auth0?  No matter, where you calling this api, if you could get the token from the auth0, then you could use this token to call the api anywhere. You mean you want to know how to call the api by using the Auth0 token in asp.net core's action?

Comment: We have written a brand new web API for our work, not from Gitbuh. Github based end point works.

Answer (score 0):

After checking with Auth0 (Its owned by Okta now) team, we cannot call web API in action running locally (localhost).